# Respect MacOS scrollbars setting when adding custom styling to scrollbars using `::-webkit-scrollbar`

Tags: html, css, macos, css-selectors, scrollbar

On MacOS, there is a setting that allow users to have scrollbars visible only when they are scrolling:

[MacOS Show scroll bars setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DZ32.png)

However, as soon as I start to update the styling of scrollbars using the `::-webkit-scrollbar` selector, the scrollbar would stay visible regardless of the setting:

```css
html::-webkit-scrollbar {
   width: 10px;
}

html::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Is there any way to update the styling of scrollbars while still respecting user's preference for showing scrollbars on MacOS?